# Разница времени в php

Tags: время, php

Привет!

У меня есть две даты в формате `timestamp`. Как мне вычислить разницу между ними и узнать сколько времени прошло?

Answer (score 7):

```
$diff = $timestamp2 - $timestamp1;

$second=$diff-(int)($diff/60)*60; // Разница между (секунды)

$days=($diff-(int)($diff/86400)*86400)/86400; // Разница между (дни)
```

/ *Думаю всё понятно, остальное сам докрутишь* /

Answer (score 7):

Начиная с PHP 5.3 можно делать так:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = new DateTime("@1356048000");
$interval = $date2->diff($date1);

echo $interval->format("Дней до конца света: %a\n");
echo $interval->format("Или: %y лет, %m месяцев, %d дней, %h часов, %i минут и %s секунд\n");
```

В данном случае будут учитываться временные зоны и, соответственно, переходы на летнее время. Кроме того, можно оперировать датами с разными временными зонами.

Comment: А как если надо узнать общее количество секунд?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
$diff = strtotime($timestamp2) - strtotime($timestamp1);
$days = floor($diff / 60*60*24);
$hours = floor($diff / 60*60);
// or whatever
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Кто минуснул, объясни, что не понравилось?

Comment: Я минуснул. $timestamp это уже подразумевается время в секундах и брать от него strtotime() неуместно.

Comment: Видимо, произошло недоразумение. Я брал timestamp как timestamp mysql: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/DATETIME.html . Поэтому и использовал strtotime(). В случае, если даты в int'ах, то тогда вы абсолютно правы. =)

Comment: Термин timestamp обычно используют для определения времени в секундах. И фраза "У меня есть две даты в формате timestamp." скорее всего значит что есть два значения содержащих две даты в секундах как POSIX-время.

Comment: Значит, вопрос был нечетким, и у автора теперь есть два варианта решения проблемы. Тем более, что не совсем понятно, что он имел в виду под "разницей между датами".

Comment: В любом случае это не учитывает переход на летнее/зимнее время

Answer (score 1):

[PHP dateDiff function for calculating real differences between dates and UNIX timestamps](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-calculate-real-differences-between-two-dates-or-timestamps/)